# How can I create variable names dinamically for a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm receiving a JSON answer, the point here is that every iteration has different names, so I don´t know if it's possible to change the variable name dynamically in a for loop. 
My code below:

```
var content;
for(var index in data){
      content += '<tr class="clickableRow">'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+(index+1)+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index].idpuntoventa1+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index].puntoventa1+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index].idtipoexhibicion1+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index].tipoexhibicion1+'</td></tr>';
}
```

I just want to change the number at the end like: idpuntoventa2, idpuntoventa3.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by doing a concatenated string, or using a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) with [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation), like so:

```js
var content;
for(var index in data){
      content += '<tr class="clickableRow">'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+(index+1)+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index]['idpuntoventa' + index]+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index]['puntoventa' + index]+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index]['idtipoexhibicion' + index]+'</td>'
      +'<td class="text-center">'+data[index]['tipoexhibicion' + index]+'</td></tr>';
}
```

Template literal would look like the following:

```
... + data[index][`idpuntoventa${index}`] + ...
```